# Using git over ssh from localhost to my Shared Hosting

Tags: version-control

I managed to install smoothly git and drush on my Shared Hosting. Cool.
Now I created there a git repository:

```
$cd public_html/drupal
$drush dl drupal
$git init
$git add .
$git commit -a -m "My Project"
```

A .git folder has been created

Now all I am trying to do is to clone my remotely Drupal installation on my local computers home or whatever:

```
git clone ssh://username@*.*.*.*:portnumber/public_html/drupal
```

it connects well I enter the password but then I got the message:
fatal: /public_html/drupal does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

What did I do wrong? All I need is to use git (somehow as svn) as versioning. I don't need to post the project on github as it is a private one.

Help appreciated

Comment: Have a read of chapter 4 of the [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book)...it taught me everything I needed to know about getting this sort of workflow set up

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about configuring server, not even software related to Drupal hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for

```
git clone ssh://username@63.23.133.162:portnumber/~/public_html/drupal
```

Note the `~` which is indicating that the public_html resides in your home directory.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you. We are using clone first time, aren't we? push/pull afterwards to push/pull the commits.

Comment: how bout for those who have no ssh on their shared server ?
no solution for them huh ? :D
guess im the only designer venturing in the development world looking for a svn soln :P